# Cross-domain socket.io breaks after 30 seconds

Tags: node.js, socket.io, cross-domain, cors

I have a simple chat server (node.js/express/socket.io) that I'm accessing from a client on a different domain.  I've already set the origins to allow everything, which has worked.  However, after about 30 seconds of inactivity from the client, it gets an error "XMLHttpRequest cannot load [url]. Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."  At that point, I can't send messages anymore unless I refresh the page.  I'm allowing the origin both with `io.set('origins', '*:*');` and with

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
});.
```

I've tried pretty much everything I can think of (disabling heartbeats, catching the error and reconnecting on the client, using `io.server.removeListener('request', io.server.listeners('request')[0]);`).  I know this is a cross-domain problem, because I don't have any issues when I run it locally.  Any ideas?

Comment: I'm using websockets.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue when I was working on a project to use Twitter-Streaming API into a chat System. The problem you are facing might be due to **Same Origin Policy** (more info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy))

Also the solution I found most Apt was **Cross-Domain Gif request**, A concept that you will find used in the *Google Analytic Script*, Full explanation of the concept can be found [here](http://www.malbecmedia.com/blog/development/cross-domain-gif-request-with-javascript/).

I hope you find this useful. It certainly did the job for me.

Comment: Isn't setting the access origin supposed to resolve issues with the same origin policy?  Also, it doesn't explain why it works initially and then stops after a certain amount of time.